# Why does my violin's A-string show signs of damage after only a week?

Tags: strings, violin

I changed my A-string on my violin due to accumulated damage (over 1 year of playing) about a week ago. Now the new A-string has tiny dings and what looks like slight unraveling. The damage seems to be localized to the lower fingerboard (near 1st position) and the bowing area. Why would this be happening?

My old strings were Dominants, as installed by the maker/seller of the violin. The new A-string is a Jargar -- this is my first trial of this brand; they were suggested to me by a fiddle-playing friend as being a "better" sound (he didn't know the terms warmer or brighter) for my style of fiddle. Is this an issue with the Jargar strings, and should I avoid them in future? In any case, I believe I will be contacting the retailer of the strings. They have been in my case for 4 months prior to use, in the packets they were shipped in.

UPDATE - I used the G-string from the same set for another violin, and it's showing dings as well. It could be this set or the brand, I suppose.

Answer (score 3):

The damage that you describe appears to be a problem with the string. From my personal experience, I faced a similar problem with some of the Dominant and the Vision strings that I have used, but only when they got somewhat old. I am not familiar with Jargar strings. I suggest you contact the seller about this problem. Also, I have never faced this problem when using steel strings such as Pirastro Chromcor or Thomastik Precision.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a possibly bad batch of strings to me. I've never used that brand, but however cheap it might be I can't imagine that any surviving brand would deliberately ship strings in that condition.

One possible thing to check though, I've found strings to deteriorate relatively rapidly (though not quite to this degree) after a great deal of climate / pressure changes. After a rather strenuous week (couple of flights in an aeroplane's baggage compartment, very hot days and rather cold nights) a couple of my strings on the violin showed premature signs of wear.